# How to remove (different) suffixes on physical file

Tags: javascript, macos, applescript, rename

I have several files with long suffixes in a folder on my desktop. I've written a JavaScript function that deletes the suffixes and returns a shortened name of the files. How do I get JavaScript to recognize the file names in the folder? There will be different files every time.

I tested the function in repl.it and got the output required. I plan to use my mac's applescript to run javascript to accomplish this.

I searched on how to get javascript to recognize the file name but research only points me to web's url and not local file names.

```
const suffix = ["_sd_mov-imx30_vpal_a4x3 IMX30i 4x3; PCM 768kbps 48kHz 16bits", "_hd_mov-proresHQ422-vpal_a16x9 ProRes 422HQ 1080/25p; PCM 1152kbps 48kHz 24bits", "_hd_mxf-xdcam422_vpal_a16x9 XDCAM HD422 1080/50i; PCM 768kbps 48kHz 24bits"];

function testFile(myString) {
let replaceSuffix = "";
let result = "";
for (let x of suffix) {
  if (myString.includes(x)) {
    result = myString.replace(x, replaceSuffix);
  }
}
  return result;
}
console.log(testFile("Apple_F001_sd_mov-imx30_vpal_a4x3 IMX30i 4x3; PCM 768kbps 48kHz 16bits.mov"));

console.log(testFile("Banana_F002_hd_mov-proresHQ422-vpal_a16x9 ProRes 422HQ 1080/25p; PCM 1152kbps 48kHz 24bits.mpg"));

console.log(testFile("Carrot_F003_hd_mxf-xdcam422_vpal_a16x9 XDCAM HD422 1080/50i; PCM 768kbps 48kHz 24bits.avi"));
```

Ideally I'd like this to happen:
- Long-file-name (Apple_F001_sd_mov-imx30_vpal_a4x3 IMX30i 4x3; PCM 768kbps 48kHz 16bits.mov) dropped into automator folder,

- applescript (runs javascript) picks it up,
  removes the suffix,
- file is renamed to the shortened-file-name (Apple_F001.mov)

The missing link is getting javascript to set the file name as the function's argument, and output the javascript's result onto the physical file.

Comment: I have two questions... Is what you really want for the filename to be renamed to is the file extension and just whatever is up to, but not including, the second underscore? The filenames that contains e.g. `1080/25p`, is that how it shows in Finder, but in Terminal it shows as e.g. `1080:25p`? If the answer to both those questions are yes, then using an Automator Folder Action with a Run Shell Script action, set to Pass input: as arguments, then with e.g. a folder named Processed within the watched folder the following `bash` compound command does what you want. Continued in next comment...

Comment: Note: The following example is bare-bones, contains no errors handling, and is meant just to demonstrate the concept. Additional coding can be used to handle errors or other conditions, i.e. if a file already exists in the Processed folder, etc. When you select Pass input: as arguments you get a `for f in "$@" do echo "$f" done` loop and the following replaces the `echo "$f"` line: `mv "$f" "$(dirname "$f")/Processed/$(awk -F_ '{print $1,$2}' OFS=_ <<<"$(basename "$f")").${f##*.}"`

Comment: @user3439894 yes and yes. It works. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad it can work for you, and as I previous said, "The following example is bare-bones, contains no errors handling ...", and while the command will process the files with the given file spec nonetheless, without error handling, an added file named e.g. `foo.bar` will be renamed `foo.bar_.bar`. Also, renamed files moved to e.g. `../Processed` can be overwritten. You can use the `-n` _option_ with the `mv` _command_, e.g. `mv -n "$f" ...` to stop that from happening.  Obviously with the `-n` _option_, a file is left in the _watched folder_ and not moved to the e.g. `../Processed` folder.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could address your problem is to keep have a HashMap (aka. Dictionary aka. Map).

Lets say the name of the file is `Apple_F001_sd_mov-imx30_vpal_a4x3 IMX30i 4x3; PCM 768kbps 48kHz 16bits.mov`

Then, you could keep a map where `Apple_F001.mov` is the key, and the value its the original filename `Apple_F001_sd_mov-imx30_vpal_a4x3 IMX30i 4x3; PCM 768kbps 48kHz 16bits.mov`.

Next, I am assuming that all files will have the same format:

- If they do, we can make a regular expression to extract the first word, following by the first alphanumeric value, and then the extension, in order to create the key.
- If they don't, then there are some harsh decision to make. My advice would be to pick a number of characters, so you can use the method substring, and then concatenate them with the extension.

```js
// So let say these are the filenames
var filenames = [
  'Apple_F001_sd_mov-imx30_vpal_a4x3 IMX30i 4x3; PCM 768kbps 48kHz 16bits.mov'
  , 'Banana_F002_hd_mov-proresHQ422-vpal_a16x9 ProRes 422HQ 1080/25p; PCM 1152kbps 48kHz 24bits.mpg'
  , 'Carrot_F003_hd_mxf-xdcam422_vpal_a16x9 XDCAM HD422 1080/50i; PCM 768kbps 48kHz 24bits.avi'];

var fileMap = {};

for (filename in filenames){
  const regex = /^([A-Za-z]+_[A-Z0-9]+)_\w[\w ;\-\/]+(\.\w+)/gm;
  var tokens = regex.exec(filenames[filename]);
  if (null != tokens){
    var key = tokens[1].concat(tokens[2]);
    var value = tokens[0];
    fileMap[key] = value;
  }
}

console.log(fileMap);
```

The result:

```
{
  "Apple_F001.mov": "Apple_F001_sd_mov-imx30_vpal_a4x3 IMX30i 4x3; PCM 768kbps 48kHz 16bits.mov",
  "Banana_F002.mpg": "Banana_F002_hd_mov-proresHQ422-vpal_a16x9 ProRes 422HQ 1080/25p; PCM 1152kbps 48kHz 24bits.mpg",
  "Carrot_F003.avi": "Carrot_F003_hd_mxf-xdcam422_vpal_a16x9 XDCAM HD422 1080/50i; PCM 768kbps 48kHz 24bits.avi"
}
```

Now, you can use the key to display the short filename, and keep track of the real filename that you will use later for accessing.

**Explanation**

The regular expression `/^([A-Za-z]+_[A-Z0-9]+)_\w[\w ;\-\/]+(\.\w+)/gm` says to extract values that matches what its in the parenthesis, in this case `^([A-Za-z]+_[A-Z0-9]+)`. The symbol `^` says that it will "start with", the parenthesis indicate that we will extract the information, `[A-Za-z]+` means one or more only alphabetic, `[A-Z0-9]+` means only capital letters and numeric, and `(\.\w+)` means we get anything after the dot (inclusive).

We iterate the filenames and execute the regular expression `regex.exec(filenames[filename])` on each of them in order to extract an array of tokens. The first token, at index 0, its the full match (the whole string that did match the criteria), the second token, at index 1, is from the first parenthesis `^([A-Za-z]+_[A-Z0-9]+)`, which is the filename, and the third token, at index 2, matches the second parenthesis `(\.\w+)` is for the filename.

Then, we create the key/value pair and add it to the map named fileMap `fileMap[key] = value;`

Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Thank you for the lengthy explanation. It works perfectly in a text editor. I used the codes in Automator under "Run JavaScript" in Utilities but nothing happens. I'm sure I'm not doing it correctly. Do you reckon using applescript entirely is a better way to rename physical files?

Comment: @Paddlepop, I'm sorry. I never used applescript. However, in applescript, I think you can run shell script. Therefore, as a replacement for regular expressions, you could use `sed` and `grep` and a quick search online seems to show that you can implement HashMaps too. Finally, you can do recursion too; however, there is a limit of 577 times.